# Do I really have to bootstrap once per component in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

Do i really have to bootstrap every component here ?

```
 import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { AppComponent1 } from './app.component1'; 
    import { AppComponent2 } from './app.component2';
    bootstrap(AppComponent1) 
    bootstrap(AppComponent2)
```

Comment: Why not? https://plnkr.co/edit/pGUepjcDX7F0fVZQ59YO?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Only if you really need two seperate instances of Angular 2 running, then it works like your proposed. 
Otherwise you should think of a host component where you load your two other components.